Add State Name in Choropleth Map
I having trouble with adding states' names into the graph. I refered to this plotly website for plotting. The last map in the this website which has text "Africa" on the graph,is what I want to achieve:
https://plotly.com/r/choropleth-maps/
Please help me with this issue. I would deeply appreciate!
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(openxlsx)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(bslib)
library(plotly)
library(tidyr)
library(scales)

extended_data <- data.frame(
  Date = c(
    "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24",
    "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/14/24", "8/14/24"
  ),
  Type = c("D", "B", "M", "F", "D", "B", "M", "F", "D", "B", "M", "F", "D", "B", "M", "F", "D", "B", "M", "F"),
  state = c(
    "AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA",
    "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD"
  ),
  value = c(
    1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0
  ),
  party = c(
    "Republican", "Republican", "Democratic", "Republican", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Republican", "Democratic",
    "Democratic", "Republican", "Democratic", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Democratic", "Democratic"
  ),
  Democratic = rep(0.50326087, 20), # Simplifying for the example
  StateFull = c(
    "Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia",
    "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland"
  ),
  Percent_byStateParty = c(
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1
  ),
  abb = c(
    "AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA",
    "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD"
  ),
  party2 = c(
    "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Democratic",
    "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic"
  )
)






# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  # theme = bslib::bs_theme(primary = "orange"),
  # Define UI for application that draws a histogram
  tabPanel("US Map",
    icon = icon("map-marker"),
    titlePanel("Map2"),

    # Organize elements horizontally using fluidRow and column
    fluidRow(
      column(
        4,
        fileInput("file2", "Choose your CSV File", accept = ".csv")
      ),
      column(
        4,
        radioButtons("voicechoice", "Choice of Voice",
          choices = c("D", "F", "B", "M"),
          selected = "D"
        ),
        bsTooltip(
          id = "voicechoice",
          title = "Select type"
        )
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(
          4,
          dateInput("Date_map", "Date:", value = "2024-08-13"),
          pickerInput(
            inputId = "USMap_state",
            label = "Select States (Max 4)",
            choices = state.name, # Make sure averaged_data$Type is available
            multiple = TRUE,
            options = list(
              maxItems = 4, placeholder = "Enter state name",
              onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
            )
          )
        ) # Close column
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(
          12,
          plotlyOutput(outputId = "Plot_Map")
        )
      ),
    )
  ), #
)



# View(averaged_data)
server <- function(input, output) {
  ## ----------
  USA_map <- reactive({
    req(input$voicechoice)
    req(input$Date_map)
    filter(extended_data, Type %in% input$voicechoice) %>%
      filter(Date %in% input$Date_map) %>%
      mutate(new_variable = runif(n(), min = 0, max = 50)) %>%
      mutate(party_numeric = ifelse(party2 == "Republican", 1, 0)) %>%
      mutate(hover = paste(
        state, "<br>",
        "State:", state, "<br>",
        "Date:", Date, "<br>",
        "Type:", Type, "<br>",
        " Party:", party2
      ))
  })

  output$Plot_Map <- renderPlotly({
    input$voicechoice
    input$Date_map

    # specify some map projection/options
    g <- list(
      scope = "usa",
      projection = list(type = "albers usa"),
      showlakes = TRUE,
      lakecolor = toRGB("white")
    )

    fig <- plot_geo(USA_map(), locationmode = "USA-states")
    fig <- fig %>% add_trace(
      z = ~party_numeric, text = ~hover, locations = ~state
    )
    fig <- fig %>% colorbar(title = "Map")
    fig <- fig %>% layout(
      title = "Map)",
      geo = g
    )

    fig
  })


  observe({
    data <- USA_map()
    print(data, n = 8, width = Inf) # Look at this output in your R console or log
  })
}



# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

I tried following codes, but it showed error:
 
    fig <- plot_geo(USA_map(), locationmode = 'USA-states', marker = list(line = l),
                    textposition = 'middle center',
                    textfont = list(color = 'black', size = 8)
    )

The warning:

Warning: 'choropleth' objects don't have these attributes: 'textposition', 'textfont'
Valid attributes include:
'autocolorscale', 'coloraxis', 'colorbar', 'colorscale', 'customdata', 'customdatasrc', 'featureidkey', 'geo', 'geojson', 'hoverinfo', 'hoverinfosrc', 'hoverlabel', 'hovertemplate', 'hovertemplatesrc', 'hovertext', 'hovertextsrc', 'ids', 'idssrc', 'legendgroup', 'legendgrouptitle', 'legendrank', 'locationmode', 'locations', 'locationssrc', 'marker', 'meta', 'metasrc', 'name', 'reversescale', 'selected', 'selectedpoints', 'showlegend', 'showscale', 'stream', 'text', 'textsrc', 'transforms', 'type', 'uid', 'uirevision', 'unselected', 'visible', 'z', 'zauto', 'zmax', 'zmid', 'zmin', 'zsrc', 'key', 'set', 'frame', 'transforms', '_isNestedKey', '_isSimpleKey', '_isGraticule', '_bbox'


See this post and this one. But you need the location of each state in your data. Before you submit a new question, be sure to check that the question has not been asked and answered elsewhere on SO.
